# AttributeError: 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'flavours' - why?

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

```
## class restaurant ##
```

> Implemented superclass

```
class Restaurant():
def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
    self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
    self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type 
def describe_restaurant(self):
    print('This restaurant is called ' + self.restaurant_name + '.')
    print('This restaurant serves dishes acoording to ' + self.cuisine_type + '.')
def open_restaurant(self, hours):
    self.hours = hours
    print(self.restaurant_name.title() + ' is opened ' + str(hours) + '!')

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
    super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
    self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
    self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
    flavours = ['chocolate', 'vanilia', 'strawberry', 'lime', 'orange']
def flavours(self):
    print('Available flavours: ')
    for flavour in flavours:
        print(flavour)
IceCreamStand  = Restaurant(' Matt IceCream ', 'ice creams')
IceCreamStand.describe_restaurant()
IceCreamStand.flavours()
```

Comment: `IceCreamStand  = Restaurant(' Matt IceCream ', 'ice creams')`: `IceCreamStand` now is a `Restaurant` **instance** and has nothing to do with `IceCreamStand` **class** (which is lost, *btw*). Name your instance `iceCreamStand` (notice the **lower case** i) and use that variable from then on. But to have `flavours` it has to be an `IceCreamStand` instance. So, do it like this: `iceCreamStand  = IceCreamStand('Matt IceCream ', 'ice creams')`.

Comment: @CristiFati Comments are not the place to answer a question, no matter how trivial you think the answer is. Comments are for *clarifying* the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Restaurant`, indeed, does not have an attribute `flavours`; `IceCreamStand` does, or at least did, until you replaced that class with an instance of `Restaurant` with `IceCreamStand = Restaurant(...)`.

Use a different variable name (camel-case for class names, snake-case with initial lowercase for objects), and create an instance of `IceCreamStand`.

```
ice_cream_stand = IceCreamStand(' Matt IceCream ', 'ice creams')
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing the loop on this as it's lonely & stale--tackling in order of magnitude:

1. Check indentation - methods need to be indented within a class (see below)
2. Inherited attributes don't need to be re-instantiated - i.e. restaurant name & cuisine type in *IceCreamStand* don't need to be instantiated outside the call to `super().__init__()` because that passes them to the `__init__()` method of *Restaurant*, making them accessible to *IceCreamStand*
3. Args passed into methods should be referenced on their own like a regular function unless you're intentionally instantiating attributes when a method is called (as opposed to when the object is created and its `__init__()` method is called)

All changes:

```py
class Restaurant:

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print('This restaurant is called ' + self.restaurant_name + '.')
        print('This restaurant serves dishes acoording to ' + self.cuisine_type + '.')

    def open_restaurant(self, hours):
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + ' is opened ' + str(hours) + '!')


class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)

        self.flavours = ['chocolate', 'vanilia', 'strawberry','lime', 'orange']

    def flavours(self):
        print('Available flavours: ')
        for flavour in self.flavours:
            print(flavour)


stand = IceCreamStand(' Matt IceCream ', 'ice creams')
stand.describe_restaurant()
stand.flavours()
```